# JAVA: convert 02 to FEB

Tags: java, date

Hallo is it possible to convert number to three first letters in month?
I hava simpla date format 01-02-2014. I separate it into field and I need to convert it with smallest possible code.

For example:
01 - JAN
02 - FEB

Thank´s ;-)

Comment: Ever heard of `SimpleDateFormat`?

Comment: put some code you tried with

Answer (score 1):

```
int month=1;
System.out.println(DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getMonths()[month-1].substring(0,3).toUpperCase());
```

Comment: (`int month=08;` might suprise you.)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the Java API `SimpleDateFormat` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use multiple options:

- Create an enum to define Months.
- Learn SimpleDateFormat
- Use Instance of DateFormat

etc...

Answer (score 0):

try this pattern : **"dd MMMM yyyy"**

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code, with `SimpleDateFormat` you can format the date as you want heres the link for it [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

```
 public static void main(String []args){
         Date dt = new Date();
         SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("d - MMM");
        System.out.println(sdf.format(dt));
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private static String   DIGIT_MONTH_FORMAT  = "dd-MM-yyyy";
private static String   STRING_MONTH_FORMAT = "dd-MMM-yyyy";

public static String ParseMonth( String date_ ) throws ParseException
{
    SimpleDateFormat    digitFormat     = new SimpleDateFormat( DIGIT_MONTH_FORMAT );
    Date                date            = digitFormat.parse( date_ );
    SimpleDateFormat    stringFormat    = new SimpleDateFormat( STRING_MONTH_FORMAT );
    String              result          = stringFormat.format( date );

    return result;

}
```